# part of nested object to flat object

Tags: javascript

I'm looking for a smart way to convert

this object

```
[{
    "id": "123",
    "text": "lorem ipsum",
    "keypart": {
        "key1": "value of key 1",
        "key2": "value of key 2"
    }
}, {
    "id": "345",
    "text": "ipsum lorem",
    "keypart": {
        "key5": "value of key 5",
        "key6": "value of key 6"
    }
}]
```

into this object

```
[{
    "id": "123",
    "text": "lorem ipsum",
    "keypart.key1": "value of key 1",
    "keypart.key2": "value of key 2"
}, {
    "id": "345",
    "text": "ipsum lorem",
    "keypart.key5": "value of key 5",
    "keypart.key6": "value of key 6"
}]
```

the keys and values ​​should be random ...

Comment: Is the property `keypart` always consistent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Your array
const array = [{
    "id": "123",
    "text": "lorem ipsum",
    "keypart": {
        "key1": "value of key 1",
        "key2": "value of key 2"
    }
}, {
    "id": "345",
    "text": "ipsum lorem",
    "keypart": {
        "key5": "value of key 5",
        "key6": "value of key 6"
    }
}]
// Transform all object in your array
const new_array = array.map(x => {
  // Create an empty object which get all transfrom element
  let z = {}
  // Transfrom each element of you object
    for(y in x) {
    if (typeof x[y] != "object") { // If it's not an object so just get it
            z[y] = x[y]     
    } else { // Else transform it in new one
      for (y1 in x[y]) {
        const propertyName = `"${y}.${y1}"`
        z[propertyName] = x[y][y1]
      }
    }
  }
  return z
})
console.log(new_array)
```

Ask if you want to have detail

Comment: You didn't say if keypart can have object too. so that will not work completly if you have for exemple `key1` as object

Answer (score 0):

You could take a recursive approach by handing over leading key parts and the object and get an array of entries.

```js
const
    flat = (o, key = '') => Object.entries(o).flatMap(([k, v]) => {
        const kk = key + (key && '.') + k;
        return v && typeof v === 'object'
            ? flat(v, kk)
            : [[kk, v]]
    }),
    data = [{ id: 123, text: "lorem ipsum", keypart: { key1: "value of key 1", key2: "value of key 2" } }, { id: 345, text: "ipsum lorem", keypart: { key5: "value of key 5", key6: "value of key 6", deepernested: { foo: "bar" } } }],
    result = data.map(o => Object.fromEntries(flat(o)));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```